# Substantive idiom for "a shoulder to cry on"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I believe there is an expression to call someone (a friend) to whom you complain about something, generally a relationship problem. Could someone point to such an idiom?

Comment: Ah, I got it, it's an "agony aunt"!

Comment: you can post an answer your own question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean [confidant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/confidant)?

> a close friend or associate to whom secrets are confided  or with whom private matters and problems are discussed.

Comment: Confidant is good too, more general maybe

Answer (score 3):

For some reason my favourite word for this is **bosom buddy**. Perhaps it can refer to someone to whom you pour all emotions you have kept buried in your bosom.

Comment: nice one, never heard of it

Comment: Ah, bosom buddies!  Like Fred Flintstone and [Barney Rubble](http://yabadabadoo.wordpress.com/barney-rubble/)!

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for was

> Agony Aunt

Comment: ... or uncle, depending on the gender.

Comment: This seems to have a pretty specific definition of being [an advice columnist for a newspaper](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=agony+aunt+definition&oq=agony+aunt+definition&aq=f&aqi=g-e1g-v1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0i9j0i15.1446.3407.0.3892.11.9.0.2.2.2.308.1997.0j2j6j1.9.0...0.0.eP8BG14UPFQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=6b4b1bdf32659c2&biw=1346&bih=478). Is that what you intended?

Comment: Point taken and you seem to be right. However, how best to express the fact that the confidence in question is about relationship and other hardship. A confident could be for anything positive or negative. Agony aunt seems best if used somehow metaphorically.

Comment: I didn't know the term, so I had to look it up. (I'm in the U.S.) Some of the definitions say it is a British expression (see Wikipedia's "advice column" entry), and some show it uncapitalized. [This Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agony_aunt) has a second definition that seems to fit what you're after.

Comment: I always thought 'agony aunt' referred to someone you complained about to others (one that caused you agony so to speak). Whatever the true usage, it's a Britishism (to Americans).